# How to access the properties of one specific patch from subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

I met one question about how to retrieve a specific patch object from subplot axes.
For instance, I create a subplot which contains many patches.Polygon objects(I assign each one different label) in a function. After I add this subplot to a figure by add_subplot, it seems that I lost access to those patches.Polygon objects I created inside the subplot. 
I know that I can get the objects by using findobj() method, however, it only returns the type of the object and its memory address. I can change the facecolor of all of the objects but what I really need is to access one specific object by name or label, such as to change the color of one patches.Ploygon instead of all of them.
I appreciate it if someone knows how to achieve that. My script is attached below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np


def drawEI(ax) :
    # draw Endcap
    x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    y0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

    step = 0.08

    xy = np.zeros((2, 4))
    print(xy)
    # theta = [for i in range(16) : ]
    theta = [345, 15, 30, 60, 75, 105, 120, 150, 165, 195, 210, 240, 255, 285, 300, 330]
    nSector = 16
    nEta = 4

    chamberPlot = {}

    for sector in range(nSector):
        for eta in range(nEta):
            # skip eta = 3
            if eta == 2 : continue
            if eta == 3 and sector%2 == 0 : continue
            #if eta == 4 :
            # print (sector, eta)
            # x1[sector][eta] = step*(1+eta)*np.cos(np.pi*theta[sector]/360.)
            # y1[sector][eta] = step*(1+eta)*np.sin(np.pi*theta[sector]/360.)
            # create polygon coordinate by numpy
            # xy = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)
            x1 = np.array([step * (1 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.),
                           step * (1 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.)])
            y1 = np.array([step * (1 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.),
                           step * (1 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.)])
            # print (x1+=x0,y1+=y0)
            xy[0] = x1 + x0
            xy[1] = y1 + y0
            newxy = xy.transpose()
            print(newxy.tolist())
            # ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(xy=list(zip(np.add(x1+x0),np.add(y1+y0))), fill=False))
            index = sector + sector * eta
            print(index)
            chamberPlot[index] = patches.Polygon(newxy.tolist(), edgecolor='black', facecolor='green')
            chamberPlot[index].set_label('EI_%s_%s'%(eta,sector))
            # ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(newxy.tolist(), edgecolor = 'black', facecolor = 'green'))
            ax.add_patch(chamberPlot[index])

    return ax

def drawEM(ax) :
    # draw Endcap
    x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    y0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

    step = 0.07

    xy = np.zeros((2, 4))
    print(xy)
    # theta = [for i in range(16) : ]
    theta = [345, 15, 30, 60, 75, 105, 120, 150, 165, 195, 210, 240, 255, 285, 300, 330]
    nSector = 16
    nEta = 5

    chamberPlot = {}

    for sector in range(nSector):
        for eta in range(nEta):
            # print (sector, eta)
            # x1[sector][eta] = step*(1+eta)*np.cos(np.pi*theta[sector]/360.)
            # y1[sector][eta] = step*(1+eta)*np.sin(np.pi*theta[sector]/360.)
            # create polygon coordinate by numpy
            # xy = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)
            x1 = np.array([step * (1 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.),
                           step * (1 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.)])
            y1 = np.array([step * (1 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.),
                           step * (1 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.)])
            # print (x1+=x0,y1+=y0)
            xy[0] = x1 + x0
            xy[1] = y1 + y0
            newxy = xy.transpose()
            print(newxy.tolist())
            # ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(xy=list(zip(np.add(x1+x0),np.add(y1+y0))), fill=False))
            index = sector + sector * eta
            print(index)
            chamberPlot[index] = patches.Polygon(newxy.tolist(), edgecolor='black', facecolor='green')
            chamberPlot[index].set_label('EM_%s_%s'%(eta,sector))
            # ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(newxy.tolist(), edgecolor = 'black', facecolor = 'green'))
            ax.add_patch(chamberPlot[index])

    return ax

def drawEO(ax) :
    # draw Endcap
    x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    y0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])

    step = 0.07

    xy = np.zeros((2, 4))
    print(xy)
    # theta = [for i in range(16) : ]
    theta = [345, 15, 30, 60, 75, 105, 120, 150, 165, 195, 210, 240, 255, 285, 300, 330]
    nSector = 16
    nEta = 6

    chamberPlot = {}

    for sector in range(nSector):
        for eta in range(nEta):
            # print (sector, eta)
            # x1[sector][eta] = step*(1+eta)*np.cos(np.pi*theta[sector]/360.)
            # y1[sector][eta] = step*(1+eta)*np.sin(np.pi*theta[sector]/360.)
            # create polygon coordinate by numpy
            # xy = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)
            x1 = np.array([step * (1 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.),
                           step * (1 + eta) * np.cos(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.)])
            y1 = np.array([step * (1 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[sector] / 180.),
                           step * (2 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.),
                           step * (1 + eta) * np.sin(np.pi * theta[(sector + 1) % 16] / 180.)])
            # print (x1+=x0,y1+=y0)
            xy[0] = x1 + x0
            xy[1] = y1 + y0
            newxy = xy.transpose()
            print(newxy.tolist())
            # ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(xy=list(zip(np.add(x1+x0),np.add(y1+y0))), fill=False))
            index = sector + sector * eta
            print(index)
            chamberPlot[index] = patches.Polygon(newxy.tolist(), edgecolor='black', facecolor='green')
            chamberPlot[index].set_label('EO_%s_%s'%(eta,sector))
            # ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(newxy.tolist(), edgecolor = 'black', facecolor = 'green'))
            ax.add_patch(chamberPlot[index])

    return ax



fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=False)

spec2 = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=2, figure=fig)

axEM = fig.add_subplot(spec2[1,0])
axEM.set_xticklabels([])
axEM.set_yticklabels([])
axEM.axis('off')

axEM = drawEM(axEM)

axEO = fig.add_subplot(spec2[0,1])
axEO.set_xticklabels([])
axEO.set_yticklabels([])
axEO.axis('off')

axEO = drawEO(axEO)

axEI = fig.add_subplot(spec2[0,0])
axEI.set_xticklabels([])
axEI.set_yticklabels([])
axEI.axis('off')

axEI = drawEI(axEI)


objs = axEI.findobj(patches.Polygon)
print (objs)
for obj in objs :
    #print (obj.label())
    obj.set_facecolor('red')  # this is ok 

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

**My question is how can I change the face color of one specific ploygon 'BM_2_5' in subplot axEM ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the axis object and the index of your Patch, you can achieve what you want this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as ptc
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pCol = ['red', 'blue']
for i in range(2):
    ax.add_patch(ptc.Polygon(np.random.rand(3, 2), fc=pCol[i]))
ax.patches[0].set_facecolor((0, 1, 0, 1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Notice how no red polygon is plotted.

EDIT: With your comment in mind

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as ptc
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pLab = ['First', 'Second']
pCol = ['red', 'blue']
for i in range(2):
    ax.add_patch(ptc.Polygon(np.random.rand(3, 2), fc=pCol[i], label=pLab[i]))
for patch in ax.patches:
    if patch.get_label() == 'First':
        patch.set_facecolor('green')
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: Returning an axis from a function should be OK.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as ptc
import numpy as np


def drawPatches(ax):
    for i in range(2):
        ax.add_patch(ptc.Polygon(np.random.rand(3, 2), fc=pCol[i],
                                 label=pLab[i]))
    return ax


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pLab = ['First', 'Second']
pCol = ['red', 'blue']
ax = drawPatches(ax)
for patch in ax.patches:
    if patch.get_label() == 'First':
        patch.set_facecolor('green')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Patol75, it is good to know by using the index to access. However, I am looking if there is a way to access the Patches by its name/label given by myself when I created them. Otherwise, someone has to know exact order of those patches in advance in order to change the properties.

Comment: thanks again. In fact, my real problem is I couldn't get the patch label out of the function. I got an empty string when I add the below two lines to my code. So this somehow turns to a question about the variable scope. I thought the axes object will still keep all information about those contained patches. 
```
for patch in axEM.patches:
    print (patch.get_label())
```

Comment: This loop is indeed right after `axEM = drawEM(axEM)`? Also, see my second edit.

Comment: you are right, I finally run through my code and got what I suppose to look. Thank you very much.